# How can I return a random value from an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin, and would like to return a random value on success.

Right now I'm trying to use:

```
     var success_message = new Array ();
     success_message[0] = "Good!";
     success_message[1] = "Ok!";
     success_message[2] = "Great!";
     success_message[3] = "Perfect!";
     success_message[4] = "Nice!";
     success_message[5] = "Awesome"; 
     var i = Math.floor(5 * Math.random())
```

Then where I need to output the value I use:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var validator = $(".contactform").validate({
        success: function(label) {
           label.addClass("valid").text(success_message[i])
        }
     }); //end form validate code
 });
```

This selects a random value but uses the same value for each success message instead of selecting a different one for each field.

Comment: @Brandon - You should refrain from drastically changing the question once it's asked. The answers will now make much less sense to anyone finding this later since the question no longer matches the answers.

Comment: You're right I thought about that after I edited it. At the time I edited it it had no answers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery validation.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can store the `messages` array and calculate the message to show as you go, like this:

```
var messages = ["Good!", "Great!", "Awesome!", "Super!", "Nice!"];
function getMessage() {
   return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
}
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/TPGY8/), then just call `getMessage` in your [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) call, like this:

```
label.addClass("valid").text(getMessage());
```

Comment: This almost works but returns the same message for each field element.

Comment: @BandonRandon - I was under the impression you had just one, just a moment :)

Comment: @BandonRandon - Updated to be random per-element, I would suggest that you may want to go a step further and remove the used message as well, so it can't be repeated.

Comment: Sorry, I should had made that clear there is one for each form element.

Comment: @BandonRandon - No worries, give it a try now :)

Comment: Great that works! Thank you, A few more questions, If I did want to make it not repeat how would I do that? Also because it's initializing on keyup It's regenerating with each keypress or mouse click. Can I use stop() or something to stop that?

Comment: @BandonRandon - You would have to do a full re-validation, actually I'm not sure how you'd handle it in your case, aside from looping through the current labels, which is fairly expensive.  It will re-generate every time by default, you could try `if(label.text() == '') label.text(getMessage())`, see if that stops your unwanted label-changing.

Comment: I think because it's adding the class of "valid" something like this should work `function successMessage() {
  if(!$("label").hasclass("valid")){
  return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    }
    }` 

but it dosen't

Answer (score 7):

We can add Method to Array.

```
Array.prototype.getRandomVal = function(){
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
};

messages.getRandomVal();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function sucess() {
 message = ["Good!","Awesome!","Super!","Nice!","Great!"];
 return message[Math.floor(Math.random() * message.length)];
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
     var validator = $(".contactform").validate({ ...
              success: function(label) {
    label.addClass("valid").text(success());
 }
      }); //end form validate code
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

A concise way of choosing a random element of the array is to use bitwise OR instead of Math.floor(). This works because bitwise operations will cause the fractional part of the number to be discarded, which achieves exactly the same result as Math.floor(). Operator precedence means that the bitwise operation happens after the multiplication. Doing bitwise OR with zero leaves the original number unaffected, except that now the fractional part is gone.

```js
const arr = ["Good!", "Great!", "Awesome!", "Super!", "Nice!"]

const randomElement = arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]

console.log(randomElement)
```