# Picking a random array element from an array

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I return a random value from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419928/how-can-i-return-a-random-value-from-an-array)
>   [Getting random value from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array)

If you have an array of:

```
days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
```

How would I randomly pick an element from this array?

Comment: Though the title of the linked duplicate is jQuery, it's actually pure JavaScript so fit here as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The title is wrong; I've fixed it.

Comment: @Tomalak nice, the duplicate link still show the old title though.. hope it's just cache.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I don't think the title gets updated in the comments, you'd have to edit it.

Comment: @Felix Hopefully it will get closed then the comment will be automatically removed..

Answer (score 2):

```
var randomDay = days[Math.floor(Math.random()*days.length)]
document.write(randomDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
days[Math.floor(Math.random()*days.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted you could make this a generic function of all `Array`s, i.e.

```
Array.prototype.getRandomElement = function () {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
};

var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday",
    randomDay = days.getRandomElement();
```